# Как компоновать элементы в Visual C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, layout

Как в Visual C# компоновать элементы? К примеру я разместил tabControl на форме и хочу чтобы он расстягивался/сужался вместе с формой?

Comment: WPF? Winforms? ASP.NET?

Comment: Работаю с Winforms

Comment: @derkode Посмотрите [мой ответ на аналогичный вопрос](http://hashcode.ru/questions/90831#90866)